# On Android 8.0 cannot find mScroller field in ViewPager (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-viewpager

I'm trying to find a 'mScroller' field id via JNIEnv.GetFieldID. On Android 5-7 it's working, but on Android 8 it's throwing following exception:

> Java.Lang.NoSuchFieldError: no type "android/widget/Scroller" found and so no field "mScroller" could be found in class "Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewPager;"

Code sample:

```
var viewPagerClass = JNIEnv.FindClass("android/support/v4/view/ViewPager");
var scrollerFieldId = JNIEnv.GetFieldID(viewPagerClass, "mScroller", "android/widget/Scroller");
```

But following code works on Android 8:

```
var scrollerClass = JNIEnv.FindClass("android/widget/Scroller");
```

Comment: why do you want to make such workarounds like reflection? it sooner or later fails

Comment: I have to change duration of scroll animation on view pager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution...

I have made a mistake and

```
"android/widget/Scroller"
```

should be

```
"Landroid/widget/Scroller;"
```